What are the essential mathematical topics required to build a strong foundation for learning Digital Signal Processing (DSP)?
I'm looking for a detailed breakdown of the key areas of mathematics that are fundamental to understanding and mastering DSP concepts. It will be great if anyone can suggest me a good book or a course to practices it. Thanks!!

@robertbristow-johnson: the link points to a Scrum website. ???

I believe that similar questions have been asked and answered several times already on this site.

Ooops.  Sometimes when I say "copy link", it doesn't take.  I didn't realize I pasted the previous contents of my clipboard into the link.  I meant to point to this question.

This is similar to this question. ----- I usually answer:.... Calculus and Differential Equations.... Complex Variables and Analysis of Complex functions.... Linear Algebra: Matrices and Determinants.... Fourier Series and Transforms.... Probability, Random Variables, and Random Processes.... Numerical Techniques (approximation such as Remes Exchange, iterative sequences like Newton-Raphson, discretizing differential equations like Euler's method.).... Metric Spaces, Hilbert Spaces, and Functional Analysis

In terms of pure mathematics topics, I would say calculus, differential equations, and linear algebra.
You also need the tools for continuous-time system analysis (e.g. Fourier and Laplace transforms), as well as the corresponding tools for discrete time (e.g. discrete-time Fourier and Z transforms).
For some things like communications, you also need a strong background in probability theory.
Background in optimization (e.g. linear and non-linear programming, machine learning) is needed in some sub-fields.
The first item above I learned in mathematics classes - all the rest was mainly in engineering classes. In those classes, they focused on specific areas that are needed for engineering applications.

I'd add a good foundation in "Signals and Systems".

@Hilmar I agree, many of the topics I listed I learned in Signals and Systems engineering courses. In my case the topics were not taught in a mathematically super-rigorous way, but sufficient to apply them to things like control theory.

The only lacking in rigor that I have seen in a Linear System Theory or Signals and Systems course (and derivatives like Control Systems Theory, Communications Systems, and DSP) is regarding the Dirac delta function.  We electrical engineers like to treat it as a function that is zero almost everywhere but it integrates to a non-zero value.  (That is contrary to what you'll learn about either Riemann or Lebesgue integration in a Real Analysis course.)
